# MySQL Query is not Executing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote this MySQLi Query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO listings (cat_id, comp, add, city, zip, state, phone, email, url, payopt, image_path, det1title, det2title, det3title, det1det, det2det, det3det) VALUES ('$cat_id','$comp','$add','$city','$zip','$state','$phone','$email','$url','$payOpt','$image_path','$det1title','$det2title','$det3title','$det1det','$det2det','$det3det')");
```

It shows the Error Query Empty.

Comment: Every heard of error handling ..

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 4):

As per usual, there is absolutely NO error handling, so you will never see that `add` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be quoted with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO listings (cat_id, comp, `add`, cit
                                    ^---^-- here
```

Never ever assume a query is succeeding. Always check return values for failure, and be pleasantly surprised when things actually work.

Comment: Okay now my new Query is:
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  `businefieds`.`listings` (
`id` ,
`cat_id` ,
`comp` ,
`add` ,
`city` ,
`zip` ,
`state` ,
`phone` ,
`email` ,
`url` ,
`payopt` ,
`image_path` ,
`det1title` ,
`det2title` ,
`det3title` ,
`det1det` ,
`det2det` ,
`det3det`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  $cat_id,  $comp,  $add,  $city,  $zip,  $state, $phone, $email, $url,  $payOpt,  $image_path, $det1title,  $det2title,  $det3title,  $det1det,  $det2det,  $det3det
)");

And it still not working.

Comment: now you've removed all the `'` quotes from the values section... You really need to learn how to check for errors/return values from db calls, e.g. `$result = mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error())`.

Comment: It worked the problem was in one of my variables the value is containing ' which was halting the whole query.

Comment: so yes, vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well...

Comment: Yes can you please tell me how can I ignore (') in all of my variables

Comment: read the link I posted. it tells you what the problem is, and how to avoid it.